# selecting MAX(val) from a sql resource in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a sql result that looks like this:

```
   MAX(val)    |   instance
17410742.00    |     0
```

I need to loop through it in php but I can't seem to select the Max(val) column. Usually I would do a something like this:

```
foreach ($sqlmax as $maxrow){
    $myvar=$maxrow['instance'];
}
```

Which returns the 'instance' value, but I can't get the syntax to retrieving the Max(val) as

```
foreach ($sqlmax as $maxrow){
    $myvar=$maxrow['Max(val)'];
}
```

doesn't work. I get the error Notice: Undefined index:

How do I select the Max(val) result in the same way I can select the 'instance' value? Thanks

Comment: alias the SQL where you have `max(val)` use `max(val) as MaxVal`

Comment: What does var_dump($maxrow) give you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `AS` in your SQL Query:

`SELECT MAX(val) AS max_val, instance FROM table WHERE instance = 0;`

Then you will be able to access the column as `$myvar=$maxrow['max_val'];`.

The query I wrote here is just an example, since you do not provide yours.

I will go ahead an assume you use mysql and will provide a link to [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

> A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name. The alias is used as the expression's column name and can be used in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses. For example:
>
> `SELECT CONCAT(last_name,', ',first_name) AS full_name FROM mytable ORDER BY full_name;`

Comment: Thanks! My sql is exactly as you have it! haha

Comment: What a lucky guess :D

Comment: I've not used aliases in sql before, thanks for that additional example, it helps me to understand it.

Answer (score 5):

Assign a column name in your query, so you can access the field easier:

```
SELECT MAX(val) AS max_value ....
```

Then you can access it with

```
$myvar=$maxrow['max_value']
```

Comment: Thanks very much (and to everyone else). That is EXACTLY what I need. Cheers! :)

Comment: Be sure to accept one of the answers so others can see this question has been answered.

Answer (score 5):

Simply do it like

```
select max(val) as mval
```

and access it like

```
$maxrow['mval']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just providing an alternate answer, in case you don't want (or are unable to) use `AS`.

The problem here was that the key of the array is case sensitive, so you have to use `$maxrow['MAX(val)']` instead of `$maxrow['Max(val)']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(val) AS instance
```

Access this

```
foreach ($sqlmax as $maxrow){
    $myvar=$maxrow['instance'];
}
```